# SVG blending mode bug in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, blending, svg-filters

Recently I'm working over a project, where I need to use SVG and it's blending mode filter.
Base element is an background image and then there are some shapes (mostly paths with solid fill).
The problem is that Chrome seems to have some difficulties with rendering - background image is too bright, some strange overbrighten rectangle appears around blended paths. 
Firefox and Opera work fine by the same time.

There's an example with extra settings to show the bug: [Live example](http://gorgeus.webmind.pl/svgbug/)

Most important part of the code:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="layer-0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" width="1097" height="835" viewBox="0 0 1097 835">
<defs>
    <filter id="img">
        <feImage xlink:href="static/img/bg.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
    </filter>

    <filter id="filter">
        <feImage result="img1" xlink:href="static/img/bg.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <feBlend mode="multiply" in="SourceGraphic" in2="img1" result="multi" />
    </filter>
</defs>

<image xlink:href="static/img/bg.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />

<g style="filter:url(#img)" height="100%" width="100%" id="fix"></g>

<circle filter="url(#filter)" class="shape" cx="560" cy="380" r="120" />
```

I had to add an extra image tag because background used in #filter is clipped (but why?).
 is a fix for Chrome, but it's not a satisfying solution.

Does anyone know what's the cause of the bug? Maybe I'm doing it wrong? I spent dozens of hours to solve this, still with no effect.

Comment: Hmmm that's weird indeed. Safari works fine too. I expect this to be a bug, perhaps this one? http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=131825&q=svg%20filter%20blend&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: Another note: if you enable hardware accelerated SVG filters in Chrome Canary, the bug disappears.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I hope new Chrome releases will have this bug fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem, and I fixed it by removing the base element from the html header. I think it is a bug in chrome.